# Open URL from node and execute javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible by using some libraries like [open](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open) or [opener](https://github.com/domenic/opener), navigate from node script to some url, and run script on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far easiest way I found is [nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/).

Comment: I was about to use this in a Visual Studio Code extension. Unfortunately, it needs JDK, and Selenium to be installed on user's machine, which is way too heavy. Have you found another way?